# Recover data from old laptop HDD: device not detected

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, usb, sata

**A little backstory:** My girlfriend's laptop has become useless after taking roughly 10 minutes to perform any action, like opening windows explorer. The device is old and should be replaced anyways, but we'd like to recover the data from it's HDD. So she bought an USB-IDE/SATA adapter (hama) but every attempt of hers failed. So it's my job now.

**The problem:** I've got an old *Seagate 500GB HDD* from a laptop running some version of Windows 10 and a *USB-IDE/SATA adapter (hama)*. The drive won't be detected by any of my rather high-end Win10 devices, neither in the explorer nor in the device manager. I've tried gaining access through the file manager on Fedora to no avail either. I've tried reconnecting and restarting as well. At this point I'm completely lost. Any suggestions except connecting it directly to the motherboard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that the computer took 10 minutes to  do anything because the disk was dying, and it was a matter of time for it to die completely. The process is now complete and there is no (easy) way to take her data out of it

Comment: The hard drive is dying or dead... Time to just let it go, sorry mate.

Comment: Does the drive spin when you connect it to a working device? Any sounds from a drive?

Comment: Did you test the adapter with a different drive & the drive with a different adaptor? Right now you have 2 potential failure points, which you need to hone to one.